# Chromium V8 internally caches Date object

Tags: javascript, datetime, chromium, v8

I need to detect a change in system time immediately (User/client's localtime), however, Chromium v8 seems to internally cache the Date object to avoid expensive call to obtain system time each time the Date object is contructed. Is there anyway to avoid this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  
  //New Date construction
  var clock = new Date();
  
  //The time when page loaded
  var start = clock.getTime();
  //Relative comapartor
  var oldTime = clock.getTime();
  
  
  //Elapse cal
  var realElapse = 0;
  var fakeElapse = 0;
  
  //Called every half second
  setInterval(tick,200);
    
  function tick(){
    //Constrution of new Date every tick
    var clock2 = new Date();
    //Get the time NOW
    var end = clock2.getTime();
    //Detect time reverse 
    if( (end-oldTime)<0){
      alert("Time has went back!");
    }
    //Gets the real elapse time (not from sysTime)
    realElapse += 200;
    //Gets the "system elapse time"
    fakeElapse += (end-oldTime);
    //Set comparator to the current time
    oldTime = end;
    $("div").html("Fake: "+fakeElapse+"; Real: "+realElapse+"; Perform: "+performance.now());
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  Time Elapse:<div></div>
</body>
```

As you can see, if you were to change the system time, forward or backward, it is only reflected after the real time has hit its minute mark (%60==0),

This only happens in Opera and Chrome, but not IE or Mozzila.

For Opera, a time backwards is immediate reflected, but not forward.

Anyway to overcome this at all?

Comment: Could you use something like [`Performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now)? It increases monotonically, irrespective of the system clock.

Comment: Also, there's [no guarantee that `tick()` will run every 200 ms.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)

Comment: I do know that there isn't a guarantee that tick() will run every 200ms, but the point is that to show the "difference in time", if I say, change the system time to 1 day later, the number difference between real and fake will be huge. Using Performance.now() has the same effect, but I will add in anyways